# CloudFoundry mongoDb access rights

Tags: mongodb, grails, cloud-foundry

I have deployed my grails application to CloudFoundry. Following code

```
GMongo mongo
def index() {
    [databases:mongo.databaseNames]
}
```

throws an exception

```
Class
com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure
Message
command failed [listDatabases]: { "serverUsed" : "/172.30.48.61:25242" , "errmsg" : "need to login" , "ok" : 0.0}

   Line | Method
->>  88 | getException     in com.mongodb.CommandResult
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   134 | throwOnError     in     ''
|   374 | getDatabaseNames in com.mongodb.Mongo
```

Why this operation (and a lot of others) is restricted? Is it ok? Is it possible to get full access on CloudFoundry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a database service on CloudFoundry, this is mapped to *one* database on a node for that service. That node is multi-tenant, there are other databases (service instances) on that node. This is why you don't have privileges to create, drop or inspect other databases on that node.